# Change defaults for kriswallsmith/Buzz browser

Tags: php, symfony, buzz

How can i change the request options for a call with a [Buzz Browser](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz) instance?

I would like to add a longer timeout to the call. Right now it triggers and exception if the legacy server takes longer then x seconds. I would like to prolong this timeout, since the legacy server always returns results, but it can take up to 40 seconds sometimes.

I'm using inside a Symfony2 controller, here's my code:

```
try {
    $buzz = new Browser();
    $legacyUrl = self::URL_LEGACY_SERVER . $urlSuffix .'?'. http_build_query($request->query->all());
    $legacyResponse = $buzz->get($legacyUrl, array());
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return $this->sendError('Request to legacy server failed.', 500);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Learn to read [source code](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/tree/a0f207ac4939978b604be9bec5d5b19baecd8165). On that GitHub page search for "timeout".

It will show you that [`AbstractClient`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/a0f207ac4939978b604be9bec5d5b19baecd8165/lib/Buzz/Client/AbstractClient.php) has a [`timeout`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Client/AbstractClient.php#L9) property and a [`setTimeout()`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Client/AbstractClient.php#L33) method:

```
abstract class AbstractClient implements ClientInterface {
    // [...]
    protected $timeout = 5;
    // [...]
    public function setTimeout($timeout) {
        $this->timeout = $timeout;
    }
    // [...]
}
```

Now you should be thinking, "how can I get to that object?". Since you are using the [`Browser`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Browser.php#L15) class, that is where you should start.

Looking at [`Browser`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Browser.php#L15)'s constructor, you can see that it sets the [`client`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Browser.php#L17) property to a class that implements [`ClientInterface`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Client/ClientInterface.php):

```
public function __construct(ClientInterface $client = null, FactoryInterface $factory = null) {
    $this->client = $client ?: new FileGetContents();
    $this->factory = $factory ?: new Factory();
}
```

Since you are not passing any arguments to the constructor it will set the client to an instance of [`FileGetContents`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Client/FileGetContents.php#L11), which extends [`AbstractStream`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Client/AbstractStream.php#L7), which in turn extends [`AbstractClient`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Client/AbstractClient.php#L5) (go through the files and see for yourself).

Since the `client` property, set in `Browser`'s constructor, is set to private you will have to find a way of getting to it. Looking through the class you will [find this](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Browser.php#L157):

```
public function getClient() { /* ... */ }
```

Okay. We now know that we can get the client by calling `getClient()`. We also know that the client has a `setTimeout()` method:

```
$buzz->getClient()->setTimeout(40);
```

Voilà.